# Why does `hostname` return "dserodio" and not "dserodio.local"?

Tags: macos, network

When I run `hostname` it returns `dserodio` instead of `dserodio.local`, which causes problems with Python servers.

I can run `sudo hostname dserodio.local` but I have to set it again after rebooting.

How can I make it the hostname `dserodio.local` definitively?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need this:

```
    sudo scutil –-set HostName dserodio.local
```

The command that you are running is *temporary*.

### Source

http://osxdaily.com/2010/09/06/change-your-mac-hostname-via-terminal/